# express router cannot get/

Tags: javascript, express, router

I have an app where I am trying to move the routes to separate files.  I keep getting a CANNOT GET/ when trying to use express router.  I've set it up the same way I have it in other apps but can't get it to work.

this is in my routes folder: index.js

```
var express    = require('express');
var router     = new express.Router();
var Blog       = require('../models/blogpost'); 
var User       = require('../models/user');
var passport   = require('passport');

router.get("/", function(req, res){
 Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
  if(err){
      console.log(err);
  } else {
      res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
  }
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my app.js file:

```
var methodOverride   = require('method-override'),
LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local'),
bodyParser       = require('body-parser'),
nodeMailer       = require('nodemailer'),
passport         = require('passport'),
mongoose         = require('mongoose'),
express          = require('express'),
request          = require("express"),
router           = express.Router(),
User             = require('./models/user'),
Blog             = require('./models/blogpost'),  
Comment          = require('./models/comment'),  
middleware       = require('./middleware'),
app              = express(),
request          = require('request'),
indexRoutes      = require('./routes/index');

//==================================
//APP CONFIG
//==================================

// mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/amy_blog");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use('/', indexRoutes);

=====================

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
console.log("================================");
console.log("The Blog server has started!");
console.log("================================");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Been racking my mind about this one for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be creating a new instance of `express.Route()`.

In your routes file remove the `new` keyword from where you assign the `router` variable. Probably just a typo.

As per the docs https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I actually added new based on some other advice but seems like that is wrong.  If I remove 'new' I get this error when trying to start the app.

router.get("/", function(req, res){
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Try getting rid of the additional router declaration in your app.js file. If that doesn't work if you put it in a git repository I'll clone and try and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`express.Router()` instance is a middleware and routing system for Express.js. In your code, there are two mistakes you are making:

1. Calling `express.Router()` with the new keyword
2. Not loading the router module in the app

Below is a simple approach you can use to make your application work:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// This route handler is for demo purposes,
// you can replace it with your own route and add other routes as desired
router.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.json({"message": "app works!"});
});

app.use("/", router); // Load the router module

app.listen(8080, () => 'Server started and is listening on port: 8080');
```